# How to parallel write to sinks in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a map DataStream with a parallelism of 8. I add two sinks to the DataStream. One is slow (Elasticsearch) the other one is fast (HDFS). However, my events are only written to HDFS after they have been flushed to ES, so it takes a magnitude longer with ES than it takes w/o ES.

```
dataStream.setParallelism(8);
dataStream.addSink(elasticsearchSink);
dataStream.addSink(hdfsSink);
```

It appears to me, that both sinks use the same thread. Is with possible by using the same source with two sinks, or do I have to add another job, one for earch sink, to write the output parallel?

I checked in the logs that Map(1/8) to Map(8/8) are getting deployed and receive data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Elasticsearch sink can not keep up with the speed at which its input is produced it slowdowns its input operator(s). This concept is called backpressure which means that a slow consumer blocks a fast producer from processing.

The only way to make your program behave as you expect (HDFS sink writing faster than Elasticsearch sink) is to buffer all records that the HDFS sink wrote but the Elasticsearch sink hasn't written yet. If the Elasticsearch sink is consistently slower you will run out of memory / disk space at some point in time.

Flink's approach to solve issues with slow consumers is backpressure.

I see two ways to fix this issue:

1. increase the parallelism of the ElasticsearchSink. This might help or not, depending on the capabilities of your Elasticsearch setup.
2. run both jobs as independent pipelines. In this case you'll have to compute all results twice.

Comment: Thinking about backpressure made me tending in the same direction, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Does `someStream.startNewChain` help?